# CMake: Forcing OS X SDK version in find_library()

Tags: macos, frameworks, cmake, osx-mavericks, darwin

I have this:

```cmake
if ( DARWIN )

   message( "target:    ${CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET}, ${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT}" )
   find_library( COREFOUNDATION_FRAMEWORK NAMES CoreFoundation
       NO_DEFAULT_PATH
       NO_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH
       NO_CMAKE_PATH
       NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH
       NO_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH
       PATHS "${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT}/System/Library/Frameworks/"
   )
   message( "framework: ${COREFOUNDATION_FRAMEWORK}" )

   ...
```

This prints:

```
target:    10.7, /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk
framework: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework
```

In other words: my CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET is set to 10.7, my CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT is correctly set and additionally I am forcing find_library() to only use that very SYSROOT to search the resp. framework.

So why does it find the 10.9 one, not the 10.7 one? What am I missing here?

Comment: Wtf?
Yes, I have 10.6 to 10.9 installed. What CMake are you using? Official binary, macports or homebrew?

Comment: Have you tried force unsetting the COREFOUNDATION_FRAMEWORK variable? I.e., in your build dir run `cmake -U COREFOUNDATION_FRAMEWORK .`

Comment: That was it! After some digging I found the reason to be the CMakeCache which had stale paths pointing to the 10.9 framework paths (I had checked this, but not thoroughly enough, it seems). 
Solved, thanks!

Still leaves the riddle of how those paths ever made it in there, our build system wasn't touched. All I did before this issue came up was to update XCode. Running CMake again after the update somehow got these 10.9 SDK paths in there, but I have no idea how.